# Where can I find Iceweasel in Debian?

Tags: debian, apt-get, iceweasel

I have recently installed Debian 10 in a Virtual Machine and wanted to install Iceweasel. At class, we were told to use $apt-cache for searching our language and then proceed with $sudo apt-get install iceweasel-l10n-es-es

However, I can't find Iceweasel through the menu nor typing $iceweasel in the terminal. I know that Iceweasel is a fork of Firefox and indeed I can see Firefox in the menu but I was sure that Iceweasel is a completely diffrent program.

Why can't I execute Iceweasel? Is there anything else I should do to complete the installation successfully?

Thanks.

P.S.: Please explain everything that I should know since I'm a debian newbie :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Iceweasel Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Firefox#Iceweasel) page you will get some more information explaining why on Debian 10 Iceweasel was replaced by Firefox thus reintroducing Firefox in Debian.

To guarantee that the move from Iceweasel to Firewall is transparent to the users, a transitional package was put in place.

This mean that Iceweasel will no longer really install Iceweasel itself but will instead install the package for Firefox.

Assuming the installation of the Iceweasel package was successful on your system, you should find Firefox on the menu and from the terminal.

Transitional packages can be safely removed safely, as once they install the new package (Firefox on your case) they will no longer serve any purpose.

Here's an example of the output of `apt-cache show` where you can find a package information and details (please note that versions might be different from yours):

```
$ apt-cache show iceweasel-l10n-es-es
Package: iceweasel-l10n-es-es
Source: firefox-esr (68.5.0esr-1~deb10u1)
Version: 1:68.5.0esr-1~deb10u1
Installed-Size: 203
Maintainer: Maintainers of Mozilla-related packages <team+pkg-mozilla@tracker.debian.org>
Architecture: all
Depends: firefox-esr-l10n-es-es
Description-en: Spanish (Spain) language package for Iceweasel - Transitional package
 This is a transitional package, it can be safely removed.
Description-md5: 375afa98d32c593ba63ded4a55cb969c
Section: localization
Priority: optional
Filename: pool/updates/main/f/firefox-esr/iceweasel-l10n-es-es_68.5.0esr-1~deb10u1_all.deb
Size: 115012
MD5sum: c4eed619ed44db98699da4a37a643e9a
SHA256: 94227186304717eb3747ca25d10735b99edb702298db30d0a60af786449233b8

Package: iceweasel-l10n-es-es
Source: firefox-esr (68.4.1esr-1~deb10u1)
Version: 1:68.4.1esr-1~deb10u1
Installed-Size: 203
Maintainer: Maintainers of Mozilla-related packages <team+pkg-mozilla@tracker.debian.org>
Architecture: all
Depends: firefox-esr-l10n-es-es
Description-en: Spanish (Spain) language package for Iceweasel - Transitional package
 This is a transitional package, it can be safely removed.
Description-md5: 375afa98d32c593ba63ded4a55cb969c
Section: oldlibs
Priority: optional
Filename: pool/main/f/firefox-esr/iceweasel-l10n-es-es_68.4.1esr-1~deb10u1_all.deb
Size: 114992
MD5sum: 3f96a2264734e7c09f854f6cefadb70c
SHA256: 962a8f9d28f78d8517b92d46ab6d4680424f2134883225b9a2ac9b6526159ca7
```